# jquery scroll to anchor different page horizontal images

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor, scrollto

I need some javascript help!

I have two pages. One has image thumbnails and the other page has those same images enlarged in an horizontal scroll navigation (image size here is around 600px height).

So page one (selected.html) looks like this:

```
    <div class="thumbs">    

    <a href="work.html#1"><img src="images/1.jpg" height="170"></a>
    <a href="work.html#2"><img src="images/2.jpg" height="170"></a>
    <a href="work.html#3"><img src="images/3.jpg" height="170"></a>
    <a href="work.html#4"><img src="images/4.jpg" height="170"></a>
    <a href="work.html#5"><img src="images/5.jpg" height="170"></a>
    <a href="work.html#6"><img src="images/6.jpg" height="170"></a>
    <a href="work.html#7"><img src="images/7.jpg" height="170"></a>
    <a href="work.html#8"><img src="images/8.jpg" height="170"></a>
</div>
```

And the second page (work.html) looks like this:

```
<div class="images">    

    <a name="1"><img src="images/1.jpg"></a>
    <a name="2"><img src="images/2.jpg"></a>
    <a name="3"><img src="images/3.jpg"></a>
    <a name="4"><img src="images/4.jpg"></a>
    <a name="5"><img src="images/5.jpg"></a>
    <a name="6"><img src="images/6.jpg"></a>
    <a name="7"><img src="images/7.jpg"></a>
    <a name="8"><img src="images/8.jpg"></a>

</div>
```

The css for the pages:

```
.thumbs {

    margin-top: 60px;   
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;  
    text-align: center;}

.thumbs img {

    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;}


.images  {

        white-space: nowrap; width: auto; margin-top: 25px; }

.images img {

        padding: 0 50px 0 50px; margin: 50px 0 0 0; max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9; /* ie8 */ }
```

My question is...what code do I need so that when I click on one thumbnail in the selected.html page it will take me to the work.html page and automatically scroll to the anchor id of the same image (and center it horizontally in the page)? I've tried the scroll-to plugin with no luck.

ANY help from someone who know what they re doing would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pass data,in your case the id of image, from one page to anoter you could use localstorage html5.
 For example if you have this page named p1.html with this code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr('id')
        localStorage["idImage"] = id;
    })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="thumbs">
    <a id="image1" href="p2.html"><img src="one.jpg" width="110" height="80"></a>
    <a id="image2" href="p2.html"><img src="two.jpg" width="110" height="80"></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and another page named p2 with this code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img{display:none;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id=localStorage["idImage"]
    $('#'+id).show()
    alert(id)
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="image1" src="big-one.jpg" width="520" height="300">
<img id="image2" src="big-two.jpg" width="520" height="300">
</body>
</html>
```

If you replace the images with your own(keeping the same sample ids), you'll see that by clicking on the thumbnail of p1.html you'll go to p2.html where a image with same id is show on the page and an alert message displays the id of the clicked image.
In the first page on click the id of link is saved in localstorage, in the second page this data it gets to show the correct image.
For the operation of the script the IDs of the first page link must be the same of images id in the second page

Comment: @user3684761: if you like this answer you can flag it in green ;) thanks.